# How do I connect MySQL Database setup on my local machine to Apache Superset on Dockers?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I have a local MySQL server and client setup. I have a running Superset instance on Docker. How to connect the MySQL to Superset so that I can add data using the SQLAlchemy URI?

Comment: As I know, If your are using docker each docker image or container consider as a separate host. so you have to make bridge to connect with them same as your local MySQL too.
There are lot of [articles](https://dev.to/truthseekers/setup-a-basic-local-php-development-environment-in-docker-kod) to create the application and database in single yml file.

Comment: The solution to this question was answered on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198052/i-have-mysql-and-apache-superset-setup-on-dockers-and-connected-by-a-bridge-netw/65249337#65249337). Let me know if need any help regarding the same

Answer (score 1):

If you have two Docker containers, you have to connect them via virtual network like this:

```
$ docker network create NETWORK_NAME
$ docker network connect NETWORK_NAME SUPERSET_CONTAINER_NAME
$ docker network connect NETWORK_NAME MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME
$ docker inspect NETWORK_NAME
```

Output of the last command will show you IP addresses of containers inside of you virtual network. Use MySQL container address for SQLAlchemy connection string in Superset.